# C# ¿Cómo obtener datos de una arraylist desde otro formulario?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

soy muy novato con C# y tengo que realizar una práctica en Visual Studio en la que un formulario padre tiene otros dos formularios hijos. En el hijo1 tengo que guardar unos datos, lo hago en una ArrayList(que no en una lista) y el hijo2 tendría que enseñarlos en un cuadro de lista.

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo "conecto","vinculo", ambos hijos? De tal forma que el hijo2 pueda obtener los datos que se guardan en el hijo1 ¿cómo sería su sintáxis? Como digo soy muy novato y no consigo encontrar cómo un hijo pueda acceder y mostrar los datos en un textlist que se encuentran almacenados(que son de diferentes tipos) en el otro hijo.

Gracias por su lectura.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando instancias el constructor y llamas a tu otro formulario podes pasar por parametros el listado que desees y del tipo que tu quieras

Ejemplo:
En tu formulario padre tenes el listado del tipo que tu quieras, este ejemplo es con un listado de tipo `string`, ese listado lo envias por parametros al instanciar la clase;

```
List<string> textos = new List<string>();

Formulario2 _formulario2 = new Formulario2(textos);
_formulario2.Show();
```

y cuando declaras tu formulario sobrecargas el constructor:

```
 public class Formulario2
 {
   private List<string> _textos;
   
   public Formulario2()
   {
     InitializeComponents();
   }
   public Formulario2(List<string> textos)
   {
     InitializeComponents();
     _textos = textos;
   }
  }
```

Comment: actualiza la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

> Lo tengo de esta forma:

```
///form2
public partial class frmAltaDeProductos : Form
    {

ArrayList tienda = new ArrayList();
       
        public frmAltaDeProductos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            frmConsulta _frmConsulta = new frmConsulta(tienda);
        }
```

Empezará vacía y se le añadirá productos a partir de un textbox, en este punto no hay problema. Una vez que los guardados, los muestro en un ListBox en otro formulario y es aquí donde no consigo que pase la información de un formulario a otro, al segundo formulario accedo por menú de barra y no por un botón.

```
 public partial class frmConsulta : Form
    {
 //form3     
        public frmConsulta()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public frmConsulta(ArrayList tienda)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
    private void LstProductos_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

Son mis primero pasos y estoy realmente perdido. Gracias por la lectura y ayuda.

Comment: borra esta respuesta, y actualiza tu pregunta.

Comment: primero que no se sabe donde estas guardando los registros en el formulario de Alta, despues en el formulario de consulta, los recibis tal cual te puse el ejemplo, algo que no estas haciendo con esta respuesta que hiciste.